# Dart How to access Map<String, Map<String, Object>> data and replace with variable

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I access search inside single product variable.

When I try to access variable is shows the instance member 'search' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression.

```
class Data {
  String search = "Something ";

  Map<String, Map<String, Object>> singleProductVariable = {
    "productPrams": {
      "search": search,
      "seller": "",
      "limit": 10,
      "skip": "",
      "order": "aesc",
      "sortBy": "_id",
      "category": "",
      "treeCategory": [],
      "subCategory": "",
      "brand": "",
      "price": [],
      "visibility": true,
      "approved": true
    }
  };

  Future<FilterProductsModel> filterFetchService(String search) async {
    QueryResult queryResult = await qlclient.query(
      QueryOptions(
          document: gql(QueryDocument.filters),
          variables: singleProductVariable),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> data = queryResult.data as Map<String, dynamic>;

    var body = FilterProductsModel.fromJson(data);
    print(data);
    return body;
  }
}
```

How can singleProductVariable search parameter replace with search variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it static like so:

```
  static String search = "Something ";

  Map<String, Map<String, Object>> singleProductVariable = {
    "productPrams": {
      "search": search,
      "seller": "",
      "limit": 10,
      "skip": "",
      "order": "aesc",
      "sortBy": "_id",
      "category": "",
      "treeCategory": [],
      "subCategory": "",
      "brand": "",
      "price": [],
      "visibility": true,
      "approved": true
    }
  };
```

Or use a constructor to initialise `singleProductVariable` while making it `late` like so:

```
class Data {
  String search = "Something";

  Data() {
    singleProductVariable = {
      "productPrams": {
        "search": search,
        "seller": "",
        "limit": 10,
        "skip": "",
        "order": "aesc",
        "sortBy": "_id",
        "category": "",
        "treeCategory": [],
        "subCategory": "",
        "brand": "",
        "price": [],
        "visibility": true,
        "approved": true
      }
    };
  }

  late Map<String, Map<String, Object>> singleProductVariable;
}
```